# validate forwarded email message is original

Tags: php, email

I'm going to build a lil' app (PHP/MySQL) that will receive forwarded emails and extract some data. how can I check if a forwarded email is really from the original source/email server and hasn't been tampered with? For example, third party companies, Foo, Inc and Sprockets, LLC, emails a user their daily data and then that user forwards that daily email to my app/system. I want to make sure they sent me the original email and didn't send me a re-created email with cooked data/stats.

Comment: Since you don't have a connection to the source to validate and a hash is not sent along to allow you to validate, I'm not sure that such a method exists.  Why not have them hook up their Foo/Sprockets/Whatever accounts to email you directly?

Comment: You need the original message to be signed with a digital signature.

Comment: Your question is not resolvable without more information.  Absent any information about trust boundaries, the only trust you can have is in your own system.  Are there external systems you can trust in this scenario, what are they, and when does a message get transferred from the other trusted source into untrusted territory?  If you have DKIM etc you *can* do these things, or at least reason about them, but I find it hard to believe in this particular scenario that there is a well-defined trusted other party.

Comment: So there's no so-so or poor man's way of doing this? Even by checking a couple of things in the email header?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the best from simple methods to check the connection with server than SSL, and to check the validity of the data than electronic signature of a trusted party.